# Create JSON Object in React.js from Rest Service

Tags: json, reactjs, mapping

I am looking for either guidance or a good example where I can map data coming from rest services to JSON "type" object which can then be used in a number of different react components.

The JSON Object will be used to map data from a few different rest services, which essentially hold very similar data which makes it better to use one object and then to bind the data to the respective React Components.

I am fairly new to React.JS and I have googled around to find a data mapper to JSON from Rest Service example.

Can anyone help?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look

Comment: (You don't need to parse anything)

Answer (score 0):

You typically don't have to do too much, at least on the front end side. As long as the REST endpoint can return JSON responses you'll be fine. Just make sure you set the appropriate Content-Type headers in the request. Note that setting the header doesn't guarantee a JSON response, the server has to be able to send it in that format.

If you're creating the REST service yourself, you have many options. If you're using node, you can simply return a javascript object. If you're using some other language like Java, C#, etc., they come with libraries that can serialize objects into JSON for you. I use JSON.net when working with C#. In these cases, because the data will be returned as a string, you'll just need to JSON.parse() it upon receiving it and then set it to the appropriate React component's state.

Comment: The rest services are provided by another project and already setup to return JSON. The React App that my team are building is split in two halves : one that displays data where some data will contain URLs, and a second one which has a user's favourites bar. Both halves contain similar data, but where I am coming from is to have our own JSON

Comment: Andy, could you post examples of the kind of responses you're receiving from the REST service, and of the kind of objects you'd like to create from it? It'd be easier to help with some real data, and more specifics on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am going to change the question